# Move Large number of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to move close 88101840 rows from one table to another. To handle log growth on the server looking at doing 10000 rows at time. Please have a look at the query below. Just want to find if this way is good or would there be a better way to do it.

```
DECLARE @Archive_Rows INT;

SET @Archive_Rows = 1;

WHILE (@Archive_Rows > 0)
  BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (10000) Audit
    OUTPUT deleted.*
    INTO AuditArchive
    WHERE EVENTYEAR = '2016';

    SET @Archive_Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
  END
```

Comment: Read this helpful article on your question:http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/

Comment: Is EVENTYEAR indexed?

Comment: If your AuditArchive is empty now and you try to move more data than should remain, maybe it is simpler to copy just the data that you plan to preserve to a new table, rename it as Audit,and delete it from current Audet table

Comment: Thanks you all . Yes. Eventyear is indexed. Ended up going through with this approach. Was much faster and log growth was minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1,

```
DECLARE @TopSize INT = 10000
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 10000
DECLARE @MaxLimit INT = 1
DECLARE @RowCount INT = 0

BEGIN TRY
    WHILE (@TopSize <= @MaxLimit)
    BEGIN
        DELETE TOP ((@TopSize) Audit
    OUTPUT deleted.*
    INTO AuditArchive
    WHERE EVENTYEAR = '2016';

        SET @RowCount = @@RowCount

        --PRINT @TopSize
        IF (
                @RowCount = 0
                OR @RowCount IS NULL
                )
            BREAK;
        ELSE
            SET @TopSize = @TopSize + @BatchSize
    END
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    --catch error
END CATCH
```

where EVENTYEAR  is index column